# How can I control a 5HP single phase motor with an Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino, motor, relay, single-phase

I am able to switch ON and OFF 1.5 HP single phase motor (current rating of 8A) using a relay with a rating of 10A, 250VAC (SRD-05VDC-SL-C.) What can be used to connect a 5HP single-phase motor (28A current rating) with an Arduino UNO? Please specify if relay, contactor or starter is required (and of what rating.)

Comment: @MissMulan It is an AC motor.

Comment: Contactors are readily available for 28A to thousands of amps, but the bigger ones tend to have higher-voltage coil inputs (so you might have to switch the contactor's coil from a relay, etc.)  Or use a variable frequency drive or motor soft-starter with enable control.

Comment: Relay specified for motor load should be used. Motors have start current, self generating current, etc. Simple relay does not suitable.

Comment: Contactors are relays for switching induction motors on and off. Use a contactor. They are rated by power. So use a 5 HP contactor.

Answer (score 1):

The required electrical parts and their ratings are as follows:

F1 - Single-pole Miniature Circuit Breaker - 63 A.

K1 - Motor Contactor - AC3, 32 A.

F2 - Bimetal Overload Relay with manual reset - Range 20 - 33 A.

Copper cable for the motor - 10 mm²

Here's the schematic.

[image]

The Arduino output drives the relay 'K11', to energise the motor contactor 'K1' and start the motor.

Should an overload occur, the 'NC' contact of the bimetal overload relay 'F2' de-energises the contactor 'K1' to stop the motor. As the Arduino input goes high, via the 'NO' contact of the overload relay, the Arduino output goes low and de-energises relay K11.

Comment: The back EMF from K11 will destroy the Arduino the first time it is de-energized. Likewise the 24V input through F2 will damage the Arduino when the contacts are closed. It is unlikely that the Arduino can drive K11 directly. You are missing a few critical components.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson - Hi Elliot, I thank you for your feedback. The schematic has been duly edited.

Comment: They make solid state relays that will switch that load. They typically need from about 3V to maybe 32V. These will start and stop the motor but they offer no protection for overload etc.